# Am I being overcharged by Azure Cosmo DB for 45MB database?

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

We use Cosmo DB as "MongoDB" , We have a database that is only 45MB in size, less than 10,000 documents across all collections.

We run light queries and writes each day, less than 3000 requests/day, also we run “MongoDB Dump” each night to dump the entire database to local server for backup, as said, the downloaded file is only around 45 MB, so I presume it is not too big.

In Feb 2018, we received a bill which is around £3,500 which is surprisingly ridiculous. it looks like we were being charged by number of requests which we knew but for whatever reason, for a 45MB database, we would not use that much!

I've also included 2 images that shows the usage in the last 7 days. From the metrics, it shows lots of requests made by "Others" which is still unknown; it shows very light in reads/writes.

Am I being overcharged by Azure?
[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Answer (score 0):

The [pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/cosmos-db/) of Azure Cosmos DB is based on the provisioned [RUs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/request-units) in your collections.

For Mongo accounts, the "Other" operations are any operation different from Insert/Update/Delete/Query/Count.

To see the details, please go to the **Monitor** service and select the **Metrics (preview)**.

[image: Monitor access]

Then you will need to select your database account, then "Mongo Requests" as the metric, and then finally add a group by "CommandName":

[image: Mongo requests]

[image: CommandName]

You should be able to see the individual commands there.

Comment: It looks like we are seeing spikes in OP_QUERY requests.  How do those differ from FIND.  Does it depend on the client DB driver?

Comment: @MikeM. OP_QUERY is the wire protocol message ( https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/#op-query ), whereas FIND is a command message.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was? I started seeing very high bills during development, we aren't even live so our traffic is super low.

I figure out about a month ago that we started seeing a huge spike in FIND requests thanks to this thread. Our regular metrics on or cosmos db page shows lots of spikes of "other" requests and this is killing our bill.

Comment: @tyjen Cosmos DB bills by the provisioned RU (you can lower it, this is unrelated to the # of commands being run). So you can just lower the provisioned RU on the dev environment and then investigate why are you having a large amount of commands.