# what is "Other" category in CosmosDB monitoring graph?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are having a problem with a spike in CosmosDB # of requests as well as requests charge in "Other" category.  What is the "Other" category.  Of course, because of this spike we get emails warning us about RUs overage.

Thanks

[Screenshot of Azure CosmosDb monitoring page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQFlk.png)

Comment: Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49533875/5641598

Comment: Any updates now?

Comment: That article was very helpful ... now we understand what "Other" is ... thanks for checking

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found the same situation on my side.

[image]

I suggest you turning on the `Diagnostics logs` and store any requests logs in the storage to check these `Other` requests.

[image]

[image]

You could follow this official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/logging#view-logs-in-log-analytics) to analysis the logs. Based on my observe, cosmos DB does have some potential requests per minute, but these are all `zero` charge.

Hope it helps you.