# How to limit usage of cosmos Database in Azure services?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am beginner in using Microsoft Azure services and I have a student subscription which provides free services for 12 months . 
[image]

I am not able to figure out what this means and how to limit the usage and my credits are being used even though I have very less data in my database(not more than 5-6 rows in each collection of mongoDB).
Can someone explain specifically what is the meaning of **7,298 / 2,976 1/Hour
Exceeded on 11/10/2018** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cosmosDb you don't pay per actual data usage itself. It's more of, you pay to have a pipe open(RU/s), and there could be going a lot of data through that pipe or no data at all, it doesn't matter because the pipe is reserverd and opened for you.

So even if your cosmosDb would be completely empty and no one is ever calling it, you will be paying for it.

Your pipe measurement is 100 RU/s. Make that absolute minimum that cosmosDb allows(not sure what exactly that is at the moment) to reduce the costs.

Another thing that matters, is that in cosmosDb you need to have separate pipe open per each collection, so to save money it kind of changes how you structure your data. You don't want to have a bunch of small collections, even though it would make sense architectuly.

RU's themseleves represent how much reading/writing computing power is reserved for your database to handle per second.

Cosmos DB gives 400 RU's per month for free. I'm assuming that's 400 RU/s, not just plain 400. So make sure all of you stuff is not exceeding 400 RU/s when combined(could be that multiple collections issue).

Comment: There are no pipes that are being charged for. The only charges are 1) reserved Request Units per second and 2) storage. And RU/s is on a per-collection basis, unless you use database-level RUs (which have a much higher minimum threshold).

Comment: I used word pipe as an analogy. I guess a bad one  My point being, you pay for RU/s that are reserved for you, not that you actually use.

Comment: Do I need a plumber? 

Comment: @Erndob https://imgur.com/a/KSelfXA you can see in this image things that are being charged . What is "other" category and how do I reduce my usage so that credits are not being reduced?

Comment: @Kitwradr First, reduce RU/s to absolute minimum it allows you, and make sure you have only one instance of cosmosdb.  I think it could be that you already used up this months free tier, so no matter what you do you will be charged, turned it off completely and restore next month within limits of the free tier. For the "Other" graph in the monitoring, have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49661005/what-is-other-category-in-cosmosdb-monitoring-graph